# How to loop through text files, find the average of each, and store it in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, loops, lapply, sapply

I have 500 text files, each with a different header and different columns of numbers, in a directory that I would like to do the following with:

1. Calculate the mean for each file
2. Store that mean into a new row in a dataframe
3. Repeat for all files

To read the file names I use:

```
#read file names
Filenames <- list.files(path = "path/", 
                            pattern = "*.txt",
                            full.names = T)
```

To calculate the mean and store into a directory I am trying variations of (and `sapply`):

```
df <- imap_dfr(Filenames, ~ vroom(.x) %>%
             summarise_if(is.numeric, mean))
```

However, the headers are being broken down into several columns, each receiving their own mean. I would like to either delete the first row header or ignore it before calculating the total file mean.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Feedback is more useful when a sample dataset with the features in question are provided. To ignore the headers though, perhaps you can set `col_names` parameter of `vroom()` to `FALSE`.

Comment: I usually do but I can't get this file open without R crashing due its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the numeric columns, `unlist` them to a vector and calculate `mean`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(vroom)

map_dbl(Filenames, ~ vroom(.x) %>% 
          select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
          unlist %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE)) -> mean_values

mean_values
```